# Need clojurescript equivalent of a three.js javascript 'loadTexture' statement

Tags: javascript, clojure, three.js, clojurescript

I am trying to apply an image to a cube in a three.js (3js) project.  I am writing it in clojurescript (cljs).  In order to do this, you need to load the image off disk and apply it to the material.  The original JavaScript statement looks like:

```
var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({map:THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("images/webgl-logo-256.jpg")})
```

The best I can come up with in cljs is:

```
(def material  (js/THREE.MeshPhongMaterial. (clj->js {:map (THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture "images/webgl-logo-256.jpg")})))
```

This works, in the sense that it doesn't give me an error, but the cube doesn't have the image applied and instead is dark blue.

Using the `type` command, I can see that the `map` property, which I assume should have the filename, is not set:

```
(type material)
function(parameters) {

    THREE.Material.call( this );

    this.type = 'MeshPhongMaterial';

    this.color = new THREE.Color( 0xffffff ); // diffuse
    this.ambient = new THREE.Color( 0xffffff );
    this.emissive = new THREE.Color( 0x000000 );
    this.specular = new THREE.Color( 0x111111 );
    this.shininess = 30;

    this.metal = false;

    this.wrapAround = false;
    this.wrapRGB = new THREE.Vector3( 1, 1, 1 );

    this.map = null;
   # ...
```

*Update: even after solving the problem (see answers below), `this.map` still showed as `null` in the `type` command output.  Thus, I think the fields in a `type` output are just default values, and you should not expect them to reflect the actual values being used (?)*

The part I'm most unsure about is the loadTexture command.  I expected it to be written something like:

```
(.-loadTexture THREE.ImageUtils "images/webgl-logo-256.jpg")
```

But this returns:

```
clojure.lang.ExceptionInfo: Unknown dot form of (. THREE.ImageUtils -loadTexture ("images/webgl-logo-256.jpg")) with classification [:cljs.analyzer/expr :cljs.analyzer/property :cljs.analyzer/expr] at line 1  {:tag :cljs/analysis-error, :file "", :line 1, :column 1}
nil
```

Does anyone know how this statement should be written in clojurescript?

Comment: Please learn how to properly [format code](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) on SO.

Answer (score 3):

`(THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture "images/webgl-logo-256.jpg")` is not a valid ClojureScript function call (at least, with tree.js). This attempt

```
(.-loadTexture THREE.ImageUtils "images/webgl-logo-256.jpg")
```

was pretty close. It should be changed to:

```
(.loadTexture (.-ImageUtils THREE) "images/webgl-logo-256.jpg")
```

In ClojureScript `.` is used for JS function calls (including methods) and `.-` for accessing object properties. More details are [here](https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/wiki/Differences-from-Clojure#host-interop).

Comment: Thank you for this.  It was the key to me solving the problem.  I posted my final answer in another post.  I should also note that any reference to the THREE object needs to be written as "js/THREE".

Answer (score 2):

Based on the suggestion from Jarlax, here is the final solution I came up with.

I implemented it in two forms: one split into two expressions, and one combined.  Note: part of the problem was using 'MeshPhongMaterial' instead of 'MeshBasicMaterial'.  I could not get the image to display when using 'MeshPhongMaterial', no matter what I did, thus I switched to using "MeshBasicMaterial".

Solution A (two lines):

```
(def mat-map (.loadTexture (.-ImageUtils js/THREE) "images/webgl-logo-256.jpg"))
(def material (js/THREE.MeshBasicMaterial. (clj->js {:map mat-map})))
```

Solution B (combined):

```
(def material (js/THREE.MeshBasicMaterial. (clj->js {:map (.loadTexture (.-ImageUtils js/THREE) "images/webgl-logo-256.jpg")})))
```

Note: you always need to prefix the THREE object with 'js/' e.g "js/THREE", otherwise you get a compile error.